# Jquery :find class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have to find a class content on click.

Following my HTML code

```
 <div class="row team">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#bannerformmodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bannerformmodal">
            <img src="img/team/Martin-Duff.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </a>
        <div class="content">
           <p>paragaraph </p>
           <p>paragaraph paragaraph </p>
           <div class="details">
             <!-- content for details div -->
           </div>
       </div>
```

By clicking on an image I need to get the HTML for details div. How do I get it?

I tried

```
$('.team .img-responsive').on('click',function(){
    var content= $(this).closest('div.content').html(); 
    console.log(content); 
})
```

But this gives me undefined. Need your help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` selects the closest matching parent element (if any). The target element is the next sibling of the clicked element's parent. For selecting the target element, you can use the `parent` and `next` methods:

```
var content = $(this).parent().next('div.content').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

div.content is a sibling of the parent of the img-responsive.  You can find the related element by going up to the closest row and then finding the nested element.  Not using next() makes it slightly less reliant on the markup layout.

```
var content= $(this).closest('.row').find('div.content').html();
```